# Polynomial annihilator method $y''+8y=5x+2e^{-x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y''+8y=5x+2e^{-x}$

It is asked to solve the equation by this method.

My result was $c_1\sin(\sqrt8x)+c_2\cos(\sqrt8x)+5x+\frac{2}{9}e^{-x}$

Then it is aked a particular solution so that $y(0)=0$ and $y'(0)=-{1/15}$

I arrived to $c_2=-\frac{2}{9}$ and to $c_1=-\frac{218}{45}$

By the last result I think something might be wrong.

Thanks

Comment: From your result, $c_2 = -\frac{2}{9}$ and $c_1 = \frac{1}{\sqrt{8}} \bigg( - 5 + \frac{2}{9} - \frac{1}{15} \bigg)$

Comment: Maybe the first part is also wrong

Comment: your particular solution is wrong

Comment: I didn't actually go through and solve the ode using the annihilator method, I just used your result, so I don't know. But you can always check by differentiating your result and seeing what comes out.

Comment: I see no mistake in my first part resolution... can someone give me the particular solution so that i can try to find the error?

Comment: Only the part of the particular solution corresponding to $x$ is wrong. That can be solved just by looking, and the result is $5x/8$. Then try again to find $c_1$ and $c_2$.

Comment: correcting the multiplications by 8 that i forgot it gave me $c_2 =-\frac{2}{9}$ and $c_1 =-\frac{329\sqrt2}{1440}$. is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given

$$\tag 1 y'' + 8y = 5x + 2e^{-x}, y(0)=0, y'(0)=-\dfrac 1{15}$$

We are asked to use the [*Annihilator Method*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilator_method), but here are some clearer [*notes*](http://dankalman.net/AUhome/classes/classesF12/odes/assignments/annihilatormethod.pdf) that I will follow.

For the homogeneous part of $(1)$, we have:

$$(D^2+8)y = 5x + 2e^{-x} \implies D^2 + 8 = 0 \implies D = \pm 2 \sqrt{2}~i$$

This gives us a homogeneous solution of:

$$y_h(x) = c_1 \cos(2 \sqrt{2} x) + c_2 \sin(2 \sqrt{2} x)$$

For the Right-Hand-Side (RHS) of $(1)$, we have the annihilator of $D^2(D+1)$, see notes if that is not clear. Applying this to both sides of the original differential 
equation we get:

$$D^2(D + 1)(D^2 + 8) y = 0 \implies D = \pm 2 \sqrt{2}~i, -1, 0, 0$$

The general solution to this homogeneous equation is:

$$y(x) = c_1 \cos(2 \sqrt{2} x) + c_2 \sin(2 \sqrt{2} x) + c_3 e^{-x} + c_4 + c_5 x$$

We eliminate the original homogeneous solution from this solution and that leaves our particular solution as:

$$y_p(x) = c_3 e^{-x} + c_4 + c_5 x$$

We now want to substitute this into $(1)$ to determine the coefficients and have:

$$y_p(x) = c_3 e^{-x} + c_4 + c_5 x, ~~y'_p(x) = -c_3 e^{-x} + c_5, ~~y''_p(x) = c_3e^{-x}$$

Substituting these into $(1)$ and equating terms yields:

$$c_3 e^{-x} + 8(c_3 e^{-x} + c_4 + c_5 x) = 9 c_3 e^{-x} + 8c_4 + 8 c_5 x = 2 e^{-x} + 5x$$

This gives $c_3 = \dfrac 29, c_4 = 0, c_5 = \dfrac 58$.

Thus our solution is:

$$y(x) = c_1 \cos(2 \sqrt{2} x) + c_2 \sin(2 \sqrt{2} x) + \dfrac 29 e^{-x} + \dfrac 58 x$$

Now, we are given the two initial conditions in $(1)$ to solve for $c_1$ and $c_2$.

From $y(0) = 0$, we have:

$$y(0) = c_1 + \dfrac 29 = 0 \implies c_1 = -\dfrac 29$$

From $y'(0)=-\dfrac 1{15}$, we need the derivative of the solution, which is:

$$y'(x) = -2 \sqrt{2} c_1 \sin(2 \sqrt{2} x) + 2 \sqrt{2} c_2 \cos(2 \sqrt{2} x) -\dfrac 29 e^{-x} + \dfrac 58$$

So, we have:

$$y'(0) = 2 \sqrt{2} c_2 -\dfrac 29 + \dfrac 58 = -\dfrac 1{15} \implies 2 \sqrt{2} c_2 = - \dfrac {169}{360} \implies c_2 = -\dfrac {169}{720 \sqrt{2}}$$

Thus, our final solution is:

$$y(x) = -\dfrac 29 \cos(2 \sqrt{2} x) -\dfrac {169}{720 \sqrt{2}} \sin(2 \sqrt{2} x) + \dfrac 29 e^{-x} + \dfrac 58 x$$

Comment: this is needlessly long and does not answer the question asked in any meaningful way.

Comment: Lets see, in the title he asks for the Annihilator method (check), in the comments he asks for a particular solution (check), in the comments he asks for the values of $c_1$ and $c_2$ (check). Did you even bother reading those things? So, what in the world are you even saying?

Comment: what might have helped, and that was pointed out in one of the comments, is he/she had $5x$ instead of $5x/8$ for a part of the particular solution. the rest was all there.